# Cannot Import from a UNC path in Spring.NET?

Tags: spring.net

I have a simple Spring.NET demo, and I'm trying to have a shared [object file](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html) that would reside on a shared drive.  This works if I pass in the [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) as a resource file to the constructor, but if use an `<import resource` construct it interprets it as relative, which is not supported.  Is there a way I can use the import statement with a UNC path?

Works:

```
<context>
  <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
  <resource uri="\\server\share\folder\SpringConfig.xml"/>
</context>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<import resource="\\server\share\folder\SpringConfig.xml"></import>
```

Error message:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': ConfigSectionResource does not support relative resources. Please use fully qualified resource name. ---> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectDefinitionStoreException: Error registering object defined in 'config [C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SpringExample\SpringExample\bin\Debug\SpringExample.vshost.exe.Config#spring/objects] at line 1' : Failed parsing element
>    ---> System.NotSupportedException: ConfigSectionResource does not support relative resources. Please use fully qualified resource name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fully qualified resource string and use forward slashes throughout:

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <import resource="file:////server/share/folder/SpringConfig.xml" />
</objects>
```

Note that file: protocol identifier is followed by *four* slashes, two belong to the protocol and two to the server location.
Worked on my machine :). This also works:

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <import resource="file://\\server\share\folder\SpringConfig.xml" />
</objects>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see my edit.  The question was actually about the `<import` statement, which seems to be behaving differently.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly; I've just tested it out and both configurations in my answer load without error.

Comment: @C.Ross Ah, finally reproduced your error ... you're configuring this in the application configuration file. I didn't think this would be relevant, but apparently it is.

Comment: However, in my test both notations in my answer work within an `<objects></objects>` block in an application configuration file. Only the configuration without the file:// protocol from your question fails.

Comment: @Marjin I had three forward slashes (`file:///server/`) similar to what I would do in a browser, apparently it needs four ...

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm..
This should work. What I don't understand is why ConfigSectionResource throw the exception.
FileSystemResource should be used by default in a non Web application.

What version of Spring.NET are you using ? Are you using CodeCondig extension ?

Anyway, this should work:

```xml
<resource uri="file://\\server\share\folder\SpringConfig.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see my edit (I had formatting problems).

Comment: I used this format in the import statement an it worked.  I'd tried it before with all forward slashes and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not certain whether UNC paths are supported or not, but if you want a fully-qualified file path, you need to use `<resource uri="file://c:/folder1/folder2/MyConfig.xml" />` IIRC.

Comment: u deserve a down vote :p
FileSystemResourceTests is your friend!